# How to update an existing custom Link that passes info to a report to work in Lightning

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, custom-link

I have a client that is migrating to Lightning and they have an existing custom link, created years ago when they were on a very restricted edition of SFDC and had who knows building out the application.
The link is on the Event object and basically runs a report but passes 3 pieces of info from the Event record to the 3 report filters.
Here is the formula for the link which doesnt work in Lightning..it runs the report but doesnt set the filters:
/00O50000001h8sV?pv0={!Event.ActivityDate}&pv1={!Course__c.Seminar_Code__c}&pv2={!Event.Location}

I thought I could just add Lightning to the beginning (it did see no syntax errors) but I get an error when clicking the link.This is what I did:
/lightning/00O50000001h8sV?pv0={!Event.ActivityDate}&pv1={!Course__c.Seminar_Code__c}&pv2={!Event.Location}

Here is the report, which is based on another, custom object with no direct relation to the Event, otherwise I would be able to just add a related list to the Event record or vise versa
[image]

In Classic, clicking the link from the Event works--it sets the filters from the data in the Event record the user is on. Does anyone know of any "Hacks" or ways to recreate this functionality in Lightning?

NOTE: I am NOT a developer, I can only use declarative config for solutions, which is what the client wants and has had previously.

Comment: It looks like [this link](https://kevanmoothien.medium.com/salesforce-reports-url-hacking-61decee8922f) could help you, but I don't have time to test at the moment.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_url.htm&type=5